# Google Maps API - Latlng function returns undefined

Tags: javascript, google-maps

I have been trying to get get google LatLng object from my lat and lng and I keep getting undefined back, even though it looks like I have been using [Google Api for LatLng](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference?hl=en-US#LatLng) as written.

```
google.maps.LatLng(-34, 151) // undefined
```

Here is my  [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/6pdypy5k/1/) as well.

Answer (score 5):

You are missing the `new` keyword.

```
new google.maps.LatLng(-34, 151)
```

[updated fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/6pdypy5k/2/)